# Top and bottom of part not coming out smooth

Tags: print-quality, extrusion, smoothing

I have an Ender 3 printer and can not figure out why the top and bottom layer of this print comes out the way it does every print. I have tried increasing the initial layer height to 0.3 mm and increasing the flow rate to 120 % with little to no results. I print on glass with gluestick and get good adhesion I also print at 215 °C with the bed at 60 °C. My bed is leveled with an index card. Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue.

[Bototm of part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMZRf.jpg)

Comment: Hi Carson. What type of material do you print with, PTEG or PLA? Could you describe in much more detail what do you mean by "comes out the way"? These two layers (first and last)... do not stick? to the hotbed? or to other layers? or are shifted against other layers? I give up :) Kudos for what you tried and what is a related setup. (Btw. please read more about heating the bed and slowing down the print to improve adhesion [e.g. here](/q/15327/). For some PLAs I go even to 90 °C before it sticks acceptable.)

Comment: It would be useful to see what the layers actually look like. Smooth is a bit relative because it could be a result of the infill your slicer uses. The bottom layer on glass should be smooth unless the bottom infill leaves gaps between different print lines.

Comment: a smaller layer height would help. might go with concentric fill instead of grid/lines, at least for the bottom layer. You can also smooth the bottom with a clothes iron, do experiment to find the right temp/pressure to melt the fine lines together.

Comment: Do you just have one solid layer for the top an bottom?  Try adding more solid top and bottom layers.